# load image to imageview using picasso

Tags: image, imageview, picasso

Im trying get image from my storage to imageview using picasso, but it wont to show the photo. It is ok with getting image from url, that means picasso working correct. Please tell me what Im doing wrong? Thanks.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view1);

    String filename = "full.jpg";
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app" + filename;

    Picasso.with(CamActivity.this)
            .load(new File(path))  //File of the image to load.
             .into(imageView);

    //Picasso.with(CamActivity.this).load("http://square.github.io/picasso/static/sample.png").into(imageView);
```

in manifest file everything is added write, read, internet.

also tried

```
    String filename = "lapin-rose.jpg";
    String baseDir =    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator+     filename;
    Picasso.with(this).load(new File(baseDir)).into(imageView);
```

nothing changes. Help please.

XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTakePicture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="picture">
</Button>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="273dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/image_view1"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try Uri method if not try this :

```
String filename = "full.jpg";
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app" + filename;


Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

Picasso.with(CamActivity.this).load(uri).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, problem is solved, was stupid mistake in application, did not turn on memory function.